# Firebase to send backend emails or format data for review

Tags: ios, email, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, backend

Just a quick question if anyone has any insight / knows any good tutorials or guides. An ios app I am making consists of user-generated content and because of App Store rules, it must provide the user with the ability to report offensive/illicit content.

When the user reports something, my app creates a node with all the information of the report on the Firebase Database. Now, I could just review by using the Firebase console, but this would be very tedious so I'd like to implement some code that, whenever a node is created under "Reports" gets all the data from the database and storage and sends it as an email to a given account or stores it in an easily reviewable format.

Does anyone know how to implement this sort of backend code?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of situation is ideally suited for Cloud Function for Firebase, which allows you to run small snippets of JavaScript code in response to events such as a node being written to the database.

I recommend that you have a look at the [Cloud Functions for Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions), specifically at the [list of sample use-cases](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases) and even more specifically at the sample of [sending a confirmation email when a user signs up for a newsletter](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/email-confirmation).